# Filter OneSignal push notifications

Tags: android, onesignal

The main idea is to filter future notifications from `OneSignal`.

I've a `FilterNotificationsAPI` call, that returns all *filtered* future notifications. Right now, I receive *all* notifications. How can I do some type of filtering?
I read that `OneSignal` provides:

1. NotificationOpenedHandler
2. NotificationReceivedHandler

But none of this seems to help my case. I guess I'd need some type of `NotificationsBeforeReceivedHandler` which does not exist. How can I solve this?